# Change/conver hash into string:value format

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, string, hash

How can I change/convert `{"-6"=>254,"-8"=>288}` hash to `"-6":254,"-8":288` string in ruby?

Comment: You should change "on" to "to" and enclose the string in single quotes (or `%["-6":254,"-8":288]`, etc.).

Answer (score 1):

```
{"-6"=>254,"-8"=>288}.to_s.gsub('=>',':') #=> "{\"-6\":254, \"-8\":288}"
```

Note:

```
"{\"-6\":254, \"-8\":288}" == '{"-6":254, "-8":288}' #=> true
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code would convert a given hash into a string similar to the format specified in your question:

```
hash = {"-6"=>254,"-8"=>288}
hash.map {|k, v| "#{k}: #{v}"}.join(", ")
```

The above code would output:

```
=> "-6: 254, -8: 288"
```

*Note:* You cannot have integers within a string, as specified in your expected output -`"-6:254, "-8":288` - they would just be characters within that string which would represent the numbers of those integers.

Hope this helps!